# How to persist Railo/app settings when deploying as WAR?

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, weblogic, war, railo

I have a Railo web application that is self-contained in a WAR file.  Deploying on a server such as Tomcat or Weblogic works fine as long as the WAR is exploded.  The problem is when the server restarts or the WAR is redeployed - it overwrites all the changes to (1) the Railo settings (like datasources) and (2) the modified files due to using the web application (uploading/modifying XML files).  The application I am deploying allows you to add datasources from the frontend and make changes to other files that the application uses.

So what I need to do is figure out where to store my files so the application data is not lost on a redeploy and how to configure Railo to use the same external directory to store all its configuration data.  Ideally, I could do this programmatically using CFML or Java code, figuring out a directory my application has read/write access to that falls outside of the exploded WAR directory.

I understand the solution may be different whether its Tomcat, Weblogic, etc., but it'd be nice if there was a common best practice way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A war file is just a zip file. So your solution could be as simple as just zipping the expanded folder and renaming the file from a file extension from .zip to .war

Not sure how often you deploy but you can turn autdeploy off. Also if you manually unzip the war file and move it to the correct location your application and all settings survive reboots. A lot depends on exactly how you need to deploy.